# Help getting Delta fence accurate

Tags: table-saw, tool-maintenance

I bought a Delta 36-725 on Craigslist after seeing a lot of really positive reviews on it, especially about its fence. However, I can't get my fence to lock down accurately at all. When the fenced isn't locked down, it has a TON of play in it. Moving it side to side causes it to twist, making it really hard to accurately place it, especially when making small adjustments. When I do lock it down, it will be out of alignment one way or the other depending on which direction it was twisted.

Is that kind of play back and forth normal for this saw? Is something broken or not setup correctly?

Here's a video that might help explain what I'm talking about: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eELYh1CX33am5iQKiN1j_8pryoRMmgmH

Comment: No familiarity with this saw, but how was the condition overall? Any signs of extended or heavy use? I'm thinking it could just be the fence is worn if none of the positive reviews mentioned anything about a squirrelly fence.

Comment: A quick web search finds people with similar problems. Sounds like a common issue (disregarding selection bias), usually solved with an aftermarket fence. e.g.: https://www.woodworkingtalk.com/f12/delta-36-725-fence-problem-184242/

Comment: Also, note that the link you have provided is doomed to be dead in an internet moment. I'd recommend replacing it with some photos showing the problem, or just describe as best you can the steps you have taken to align and use the fence if you feel you need more detail.

Comment: If you tighten it in 2 steps first to about where you want it but still able to move it slightly this should work this is the method I use on my similar stile fence.

Answer (score 3):

I had tightened the adjustment screws down further based on some other comments I've seen online, but it wasn't until I went to Lowe's last night and looked at the one on display that I realized that they needed to be screwed in even further. After adjusting them so that they were actually below the surface by a few turns, and then adjusting it from there to make them even, it finally slides back and forth smoothly and locks down consistently.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to share your findings!

Comment: So the screws were just too loose? Ha! I wonder how many people bought a third-party fence when all they needed was a screwdriver :-)