# Advice on my Delta Unifence?

Tags: table-saw, fence

My Unifence handle is not staying down/engaged. It’s somehow to do with the handle/cam lever and/or thrust washer and/or…? If I hold itin position/down the fence locks tight in place as it should...no lateral movement.  But as soon as I let go of the handle, it drops away from thrust washer allowing fence to travel.

It’s not the slide(s) assembly or the adjustment nuts…handle self-releases as soon as I let go of it no matter how tight or loose they are set. I think the problem has to do with the answer to the question: what keeps the handle down/locked in the first place?  Are either the cam or thrust washer considered "wear" or "consumable" items?  Is there something that helps create friction or "stick" that is supposed to between the cam and the washer that has worn away?

My hope is this is somehow a general, or regular, or known issue with a “tribal knowledge” fix. I am happy to take/post pics or a short vid of handle self-releasing if it would help.

Honestly, I’d replace the whole fence (not rail) assembly if I could, but kinda hard to find something I know would fit/work, i.e. an exact (where it matters) replacement.

Comment: Any relevant help here, https://www.finewoodworking.com/forum/delta-unifence-wont-lock-onto-rail ?

Comment: Also see: https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/10018/5572 (not sure if a "unifence" is the same thing as mentioned in this Q&A...) (Also, the manual for this fence discusses what to do if the lock doesn't engage.)

Comment: (1 of 2) The frustrating thing is the general mechanism, and therefore standard fix, is so simple/trivial  The two front set screws that adjust the slides forward or back, and therefore control how the cam part of handle registers against the rail, are the only things that can be adjusted, but for me there is no adjustment that works.  I.E. I have, multiple times, started with the screws either all/most the way out (or in), then slowly adjusted them in (or out) until the cam part just barely engages (or is just not quite able to be locked down).

Comment: (2 of 2)  To be clear I read everything I could find on internet already and have dinked with this several times, each time for a while...there just doesn't seem to be >>any<< adjustment setting that allows the cam to properly engage and lock down the fence. And, more worrisome, even if I got it there, then when I went to go align fence to the blade, I'd have to adjust one or other of set screws, almost certainly bollocking things up again.  I just feel there is something wrong at point of contact, like someone snuck in and lubricated it or something...sigh :--/

Comment: Well, the manual shows that there are two "fibre" washers that can be considered consumables, but I just glanced at the exploded view. To be clear: you have _read_ your _manual_ where it tells you how to adjust this lever action? If you have any hope of getting help from the hive-mind, you will really have to be clear about what exactly you have tried so far. (Also, if any of your comments are hiding relevant information, that should be put in the body of the question with an [edit].)

Comment: @jdv, as mentioned, I am >>far<< too familiar with information regarding Unifence that is readily available on the internet, including parts sites, diagrams, manuals, videos, etc.  Whatever the problem is, and I've described it above as best I can, the answer not anywhere there.  And as mentioned, adjusting the fence is trivially easy (that assumption being fence is willing to be adjusted...).  Whatever is actually the problem is not covered in any manual or troubleshooting tips anywhere I have been can find.

Comment: I think I'll put a call into Delta and see if they can offer any guidance...thanks to both for time and suggestions :--)

Comment: @mblatz01, that's fine, which is why I said "if you want to leverage the hive-mind ...". Nowhere in the _question_ do you clearly mention the manual, or how the manual instructions for this problem do not help. I have no doubt you have found an interesting different problem. But any assistance is futile without knowing exactly what you have tried. SE sites are not internet forums. This can be both good and bad depending on the nature of the problem, but it means that asking a question means redoing all the boring explanation _in the question_ again so we all start from the same place.